# pg_dump and the superuser

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

PostgreSQL lets me connect as superuser if I am system user postgres:

```
[T] jeff@nantes-5p:~ $ sudo -u postgres psql
psql (10.15 (Ubuntu 10.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.1))
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

As a result, I've cleverly not created a superuser.  But it appears that pg_dump does not offer this shortcut:

```
130,[T] jeff@nantes-5p:~ $ sudo -u postgres pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "postgres" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
1,[T] jeff@nantes-5p:~ $ sudo -u postgres pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -w
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "postgres" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
1,[T] jeff@nantes-5p:~ $ sudo -u postgres pg_dump -h localhost -w
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "postgres" failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
1,[T] jeff@nantes-5p:~ $
```

Did I miss something?  It seems inconsistent, and a bit silly that creating a superuser just requires root but dumping tables requires something that root can just do.

Comment: The difference is you are connecting to a local socket in the first case and `localhost` in the other cases. Also you do not need to do the `sudo`, just run `pg_dump -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -w`. You are confusing the system user postgres with the database user postgres.   In either case the `auth` method required(password vs peer or trust) is set in your `pg_hba.conf` file and is obviously different for socket vs localhost.

Comment: Ah, right: the sudo solution works because it's using the unix domain socket, which is only available to user postres, and specifying a host or port avoids using the socket.  So this works: `sudo -u postgres pg_dump -w my-dbname`.

Comment: There are quite a few misunderstandings in your comment. Rather then reprise the documentation I will point you at [pg_hba](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) and [libpq](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).  Also I would recommend looking at your `pg_hba.conf` file to see what is actually there.